# Array Serialize Gives Qualified Class name using Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, serialization, jackson

I am using JSON Serialization. Here is my code. 
I need to change the qualified class name using Annotation. I don't have to use Map or another class. Name should be picked from Annotation.

```
package com.test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;


@JsonTypeName("Product")
@JsonRootName("Product")
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
public class ProductDTO {
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Test Class:-

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class ProductDTOTestCase {
    @Test
    public void testPersistAndFindById() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
        //mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY);

        ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO();
        productDTO.setDescription("Product 4 - Test");

        ArrayList<ProductDTO> arrayList = new ArrayList<ProductDTO>();
        arrayList.add(productDTO);

        // Do not change this line
        String writeValueAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(arrayList);
        System.out.println(writeValueAsString);
//      /Assert.assertTrue(writeValueAsString.contentEquals("Entity"));
    }


}
```

It gives me:-

```
 [["com.test.ProductDTO",{"name":null,"description":"Product 4 - Test"}]]
```

But I want

```
[["Product",{"name":null,"description":"Product 4 - Test"}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you serialize basically a generic ArrayList (the Class of your ArrayList, since no generic info is available).

As a consequence, our basic List.class has simply no @JsonTypeInfo annotation or whatsoever about the items contained, no type information is available, that's why you get the simple name of your class.

Solutions:

- Use custom sub-class like "class MyList extends ArrayList { }" --> it will NOT suffer from this kind of type erasure (generic type info is hidden, but retained) and will work as expected, OR
- Use ObjectWriter and specify full generic type in your serialization: mapper.writerForType(listType).writeValueAsString() (listType you can construct using TypeFactory or using TypeReference)